# How to display excel chart in browser?

Tags: javascript, excel, activex

I have an excel sheet containing excel chart. I am able to display entier excel sheet on browser using an iframe. However, I only want to display the chart present inside the excel sheet on the browser.

How do I achieve this? I see that it needs Javascript + ActiveX APIs. I tried but couldn't get it to work.

Please see code given below. It doesn't work as I am not able to set data attribute of "object" tag dynamically. It doesn't allow.

```
<object id="objFrame" data="" type="application/vnd.ms-excel"></object>

<script>
var Excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application"); 
Excel.Visible = false;
document.getElementById("objFrame").data  = Excel.Workbooks.Open("Test.xls").Sheets("Chart1");
Excel.Quit();
</script>
```

Is there any other way to achieve this? Please post sample code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should check [this tool](http://www.aspose.com/categories/file-format-components/aspose.cells-for-.net-and-java/default.aspx) out, I believe this will achieve exactly what you're looking for, without having to load the memory bloat/leak known as the Office COM server, into browser memory, and feel like your violating security best practices.

Comment: Thanks. But I want to use only Javascript + ActiveX to achieve this. No third party tools.

Answer (score 1):

[SpreadsheetGear for .NET](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) provides the ability to load Excel workbooks, plug in values, calculate and then render a chart (or a range of cells which contain a chart) on the server which can then be displayed in the browser. You can see live ASP.NET (C# and VB) samples [here](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/imaging.aspx).

Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC

Comment: Thanks. But I want to use only Javascript + ActiveX to achieve this. No third party tools.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check [the Funfun Excel add-in](https://www.funfun.io/1/msaddin). Basically, Funfun allows you to use JavaScript directly in your Excel as the image below shows.

[image]

Here I have a sample chart which is plotted using HighChart.js with data in the spreadsheet. You could see the chart at the right side of your Excel. You could then click the button at the left-top corner of the chart to open the chart in default browser. Which looks like this.

[image]

Also, if you want to show both the spreadsheet and the chart in the browser. You have two option.

**The first** is to use Excel online. Then you have the same thing on your browser as in your local Excel.

[image]

**As for the second option,** Funfun also has an online editor in which you could explore with your JavaScript code alongside with your data.

[image]

You could check the detailed code of this example on the link below.

https://www.funfun.io/1/edit/5a439b96b848f771fbcdedf0

***Disclosure: I'm a developer of Funfun***